# Как передать параметры в NancyFX?

Tags: c#

Есть маршрут

```
 Get["/{url}/{digit}"
```

Если на вход поступает нижняя конструкция, то все работает

```
localhost:8888/yandex.ru/2
```

Однако если передать следующий параметр, система не находит этот маршрут.

```
localhost:8888/http://www.yandex.ru/2
```

Что не так в моем роуте?